# minmax функция в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли в питоне синтаксис для minmax функции из других языков?

Надо такое поведение:

```
    min, max = None, None

    if class_1.value < class_2.value:
        min, max = class_1, class_2
    else:
        min, max = class_2, class_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
min, max = sorted([class_1, class_2], key=lambda x: x.value)
```

Функция, соответственно:

```
def minmax(a, b):
    return sorted([a, b], key=lambda x: x.value)

min, max = minmax(class_1, class_2)
```

Но лучше сделать аналогично тому, как у вас в вопросе:

```
def minmax(a, b):
    return (a, b) if a.value < b.value else (b, a)
```